# How to connect server name and my IP in nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualbox

I want to create a simple static html page by nginx.So...I write html and all .conf files. If I write down 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 in Mozilla it's OK and worked.But I can't visit my html page by server name or IP(i get IP by icanhazip.com) . Where is my mistake? Where should I connect my IP with server name?
P.S. using common nginx.conf

If I write in etc/hosts connection between IP and server name and use "sudo ifconfig enp0s3 (here is my IP)" than no one site except my will work.And also I can't enter my site by other devices

**site1.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80 ;
  root /var/www/html/site1;
  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name     www.oleghelp1.com       oleghelp1.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is not related to nginx. The problem is that your domain name is not registered with an external DNS. Presumably, you already own this domain name. The next thing you need to do is connect your domain name with an IP address that is accessible to the internet. This is something that you[DNS Made Easy](https://dnsmadeeasy.com/).